# How can I make this code better / quicker?

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have a collection of working codes, that removes words from a word table, and reformats the size of the table. I know i'm repeating, in the code, so i'd like to make this more streamlined, and in the hope that by doing this, the code will become a little quicker to run.

I'm a complete noob to vba, so I've scoured the web, and ad-hocced the working code together. The table im working on is 150 rows, by 10 columns, but the rows will change on a weekly basis.

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub alterRota()

    Dim manager
    manager = "Manager"

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = manager
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Dim bar
    bar = "Bar"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = bar
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Dim kitchen
    kitchen = "Kitchen"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = kitchen
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    Dim lead
    lead = "Lead"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = lead
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Dim cleaning
    cleaning = "Cleaning"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = cleaning
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Dim floor
    floor = "Floor"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = floor
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll




    Dim timeoff
    timeoff = "Time Off"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = timeoff
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Dim startoff
    startoff = "04:00 - 00:00"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = startoff
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Dim endoff
    endoff = "00:00 - 04:00"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = endoff
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Dim linebreaks
    linebreaks = "^p"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = linebreaks
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Dim employee
    employee = "Employee"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = employee
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    Dim tr As Row
    For Each tr In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
    tr.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
    tr.Height = 9
    Next tr


    End Sub
```

Comment: You need one block of code (as a procedure) that does all of the `Find` stuff, and an array of the text that you want to use to find (what you're using `timeoff` and `bar` for in your existing code) that you can loop through to call that procedure. That would simplify it greatly, as every call to the `Find` block does exactly the same thing except for the specific text it's looking to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be re-written as follows...

```
Option Explicit

Sub alterRota()

    Dim searchFor As Variant
    searchFor = Array("Manager", "Bar", "Kitchen", . . . ) 'add your other words accordingly

    Dim i As Long
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        For i = LBound(searchFor) To UBound(searchFor)
            .Text = searchFor(i)
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next i
    End With

    Dim tr As Row
    For Each tr In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
        tr.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
        tr.Height = 9
    Next tr

End Sub
```